# Pandas groupby multi conditions and date difference calculation

Tags: pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby, pivot-table, hierarchical-clustering

I am stuck understanding the method to use. I have the following dataframe:

```
df = {'CODE': ['BBLGLC70M','BBLGLC70M','ZZTNRD77', 'ZZTNRD77', 'AACCBD', 'AACCBD', 'BCCDN', 'BCCDN', 'BCCDN'],
      'DATE': ['16/05/2019','25/09/2019', '16/03/2020', '27/02/2020', '16/07/2020', '21/07/2020', '13/02/2020', '23/07/2020', '27/02/2020'],
      'TYPE': ['PRI', 'PRI', 'PRI', 'PRI', 'PUB', 'PUB', 'PUB', 'PRI', 'PUB'],
      'DESC' : ['KO', 'OK', 'KO', 'KO', 'KO', 'OK', 'KO', 'OK', 'OK']
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format = '%d/%m/%Y')
df
```

[image]

I need to:

1. groupby the same 'CODE',
2. check if the 'DESC' is not the same
3. check if the 'TYPE' is the same
4. calculate the month difference between dates that satisfy the previous 2 commands

The expected output is the below:

[image]

Comment: hi, what did you try yourself already ?

Comment: Hello, I have tried creating a pivot table with code, type and date as index and desc as values equal to size(). Then I have df.groupby(level=0)['DATE'].transform(lambda x: x[0] - x[1]) here is were I get it wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code uses [.drop_duplicates()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and [.duplicated()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) to keep or throw out rows from your dataframe that have duplicate values.

How would you calculate a month's difference? A month can be 28, 30 or 31 days. You could divide the end result by 30 and get an indication of the number of months difference. So I kept it in days for now.

```
import pandas as pd

df = {'CODE': ['BBLGLC70M','BBLGLC70M','ZZTNRD77', 'ZZTNRD77', 'AACCBD', 'AACCBD', 'BCCDN', 'BCCDN', 'BCCDN'],
      'DATE': ['16/05/2019','25/09/2019', '16/03/2020', '27/02/2020', '16/07/2020', '21/07/2020', '13/02/2020', '23/07/2020', '27/02/2020'],
      'TYPE': ['PRI', 'PRI', 'PRI', 'PRI', 'PUB', 'PUB', 'PUB', 'PRI', 'PUB'],
      'DESC' : ['KO', 'OK', 'KO', 'KO', 'KO', 'OK', 'KO', 'OK', 'OK']
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format = '%d/%m/%Y')

# only keep rows that have the same code and type 
df = df[df.duplicated(subset=['CODE', 'TYPE'], keep=False)]

# throw out rows that have the same code and desc
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['CODE', 'DESC'], keep=False)

# find previous date
df = df.sort_values(by=['CODE', 'DATE'])
df['previous_date'] = df.groupby('CODE')['DATE'].transform('shift')

# drop rows that don't have a previous date
df = df.dropna()

# calculate the difference between current date and previous date
df['difference_in_dates'] = (df['DATE'] - df['previous_date'])
```

This results in the following df:

```
CODE        DATE        TYPE    DESC    previous_date   difference_in_dates
AACCBD      2020-07-21  PUB     OK      2020-07-16      5 days
BBLGLC70M   2019-09-25  PRI     OK      2019-05-16      132 days
BCCDN       2020-02-27  PUB     OK      2020-02-13      14 days
```